# AWS Django project throws AttributeError at /contact when sending a form

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, attributeerror

I've been working on my first website with django, it's deployed to aws with zappa. The page is using Lambda, S3, Apigateway and cloudfront. When I get the api url from my terminal after deployment/update the form works fine. But when I try to send the form from my actual website urls I've set up in aws the website throws the following error:

```
AttributeError at /contact

'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    https://asdasdasd.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/contact
Django Version:     2.1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Exception Location:     /var/task/django/utils/http.py in is_same_domain, line 278
Python Executable:  /var/lang/bin/python3.8
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:    

['/var/task',
 '/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/opt/python',
 '/var/runtime',
 '/var/lang/lib/python38.zip',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.8',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/opt/python',
 '/var/task']

Server time:    Thu, 7 May 2020 06:13:04 +0000
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
"""
Django settings for my_website project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG']

# EMAIL_HOST =

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '(my_api_numbers).execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'mywebsite.co/']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'web_pages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'



EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'





AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'aws_accesskey'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'aws_secretkey'

AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-1'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

STATIC_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None 

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] 

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = 'mywebsite.co/'

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ['mywebsite.co/']

´´´

and here's my views file:
```

def contact(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    message_name = request.POST['name']
    message_email = request.POST['email']
    message_organization = request.POST['organization']
    message_title = request.POST['title']
    message_message = request.POST['message']
    message_field = request.POST['subject']
    message_consent = request.POST['consent']

    message_info = "Name: {} \n Email: {} \n Organization: {} \n Field: {} \n Consent: {} \n \n Message: \n {}".format(message_name, message_email, message_organization, message_field, message_consent, message_message)

    send_mail(
        message_title,
        message_info,
        'forms@company.co',  # from email
        ['sales@company.co'],  # To email
    )

    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', {'name': message_name})

else:
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', {})
```

I've tried plenty of configuring in the aws end but I might be missing out something there ...or in the code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is a plain *list of strings*? You're not perchance appending anything to that list afterwards somewhere?

Comment: For what I've understood, yes it is a plain list of strings. I'm not appending anything in the code that I know of.